# Enabling Temperature Support on LSI MegaRaid Cards

Tags: physical-environment, megaraid, megacli

I've got two IBM ServeRAID M5014 SAS/SATA Controller cards in two different machines. One reports drive temperatures, the other does not. I am hopping that it is some type of megacli option that I can set. However, I have looked throughout the megacli documentation without any hints that this is a configurable option. Does anyone have any experience with these cards that can tell me if a firmware upgrade will fix this discrepancy? The card that is currently working(reporting temperatures) lives in its native IBM Systems X configuration while the second card, which is currently operational besides reporting temperatures does not live in a native Systems X machine but is more of a... Frankenstein, for lack of better words.

As another data point, does anyone have one of these cards in a non Systems X machine that is reporting temperatures?

Below is a dump of relevant information for archival purposes and for those of you that are interested.

First off, while the cards are both M5014s they are different versions. The one reporting temperatures is:

```
                    Versions
                ================
Product Name    : ServeRAID M5014 SAS/SATA Controller
Serial No       : SV13815228
FW Package Build: 12.12.0-0065

                    Mfg. Data
                ================
Mfg. Date       : 09/17/11
Rework Date     : 00/00/00
Revision No     : 80B
Battery FRU     : N/A

                Image Versions in Flash:
                ================
FW Version         : 2.120.143-1325
BIOS Version       : 3.22.00_4.11.05.00_0x05060000
Preboot CLI Version: 04.04-017:#%00008
WebBIOS Version    : 6.0-40-e_35-Rel
NVDATA Version     : 2.09.03-0020
Boot Block Version : 2.02.00.00-0000
BOOT Version       : 09.250.01.219

                Pending Images in Flash
                ================
None

                PCI Info
                ================
Controller Id   : 0000
Vendor Id       : 1000
Device Id       : 0079
SubVendorId     : 1014
SubDeviceId     : 03c7

Host Interface  : PCIE
```

And the one not reporting temperature is:

```
                    Versions
                ================
Product Name    : ServeRAID M5014 SAS/SATA Controller
Serial No       : SV02102642
FW Package Build: 12.0.1-0097

                    Mfg. Data
                ================
Mfg. Date       : 05/17/10
Rework Date     : 00/00/00
Revision No     :
Battery FRU     : N/A

                Image Versions in Flash:
                ================
BIOS Version       : 3.09.00
FW Version         : 2.0.33-0901
Preboot CLI Version: 02.00-015:#%00008
WebBIOS Version    : 3.0-22-e_12-Rel
NVDATA Version     : 2.02.0043
Boot Block Version : 2.00.00.00-0018
BOOT Version       : 01.250.04.219

                Pending Images in Flash
                ================
None

                PCI Info
                ================
Controller Id   : 0000
Vendor Id       : 1000
Device Id       : 0079
SubVendorId     : 1014
SubDeviceId     : 03c7

Host Interface  : PCIE
```

Probing for drive temperature results in:

```
sudo megacli -PDList -aALL -NoLog | grep -m1 "Drive Temperature"
Drive Temperature :28C (82.40 F)
```

And

```
sudo megacli -PDList -aALL -NoLog | grep -m1 "Drive Temperature"
Drive Temperature : N/A
```

Further investigation shows that temperature is not supported on the second card. From

```
sudo megacli -AdpAllInfo -aAll

                Supported PD Operations
                ================
Support Temperature                     : Yes
```

And not enabled on the second card.

```
                Supported PD Operations
                ================
Support Temperature                     : No
```

Here are the Physical Device details:

Card #1

```
Enclosure Device ID: 8
Slot Number: 8
Drive's postion: DiskGroup: 7, Span: 0, Arm: 0
Enclosure position: 1
Device Id: 19
WWN: 5000c5001130d3ca
Sequence Number: 2
Media Error Count: 0
Other Error Count: 0
Predictive Failure Count: 0
Last Predictive Failure Event Seq Number: 0
PD Type: SATA

Raw Size: 1.364 TB [0xaea87b30 Sectors]
Non Coerced Size: 1.363 TB [0xae987b30 Sectors]
Coerced Size: 1.363 TB [0xae81a800 Sectors]
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
Device Firmware Level: CC1H
Shield Counter: 0
Successful diagnostics completion on :  N/A
SAS Address(0): 0x500507603947ae49
Connected Port Number: 0(path0)
Inquiry Data:             9VS1GZVVST31500341AS                            CC1H
FDE Capable: Not Capable
FDE Enable: Disable
Secured: Unsecured
Locked: Unlocked
Needs EKM Attention: No
Foreign State: None
Device Speed: 3.0Gb/s
Link Speed: 6.0Gb/s
Media Type: Hard Disk Device
Drive Temperature :35C (95.00 F)
PI Eligibility:  No
Drive is formatted for PI information:  No
PI: No PI
Port-0 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: 6.0Gb/s
Drive has flagged a S.M.A.R.T alert : No
```

And the second card:

```
Enclosure Device ID: 252
Slot Number: 6
Drive's postion: DiskGroup: 6, Span: 0, Arm: 0
Enclosure position: N/A
Device Id: 18
WWN:
Sequence Number: 2
Media Error Count: 0
Other Error Count: 0
Predictive Failure Count: 0
Last Predictive Failure Event Seq Number: 0
PD Type: SATA

Raw Size: 1.364 TB [0xaea87b30 Sectors]
Non Coerced Size: 1.363 TB [0xae987b30 Sectors]
Coerced Size: 1.363 TB [0xae81a800 Sectors]
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
Device Firmware Level: CC1J
Shield Counter: 0
Successful diagnostics completion on :  N/A
SAS Address(0): 0x4433221106000000
Connected Port Number: 4(path0)
Inquiry Data:             9VS0FTMYST31500341AS                            CC1J
FDE Capable: Not Capable
FDE Enable: Disable
Secured: Unsecured
Locked: Unlocked
Needs EKM Attention: No
Foreign State: None
Device Speed: 3.0Gb/s
Link Speed: 3.0Gb/s
Media Type: Hard Disk Device
Drive Temperature : N/A
PI Eligibility:  No
Drive is formatted for PI information:  No
PI: No PI
Port-0 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: 3.0Gb/s
Drive has flagged a S.M.A.R.T alert : No
```

Here is a diff of the "sudo megacli -AdpAllInfo -aAll" (diff <(sort card1.txt) <(sort card2.txt)):

```
72d70
< Auto Enhanced Import             : No
76c74
< Battery Warning                  : Enabled
---
> Battery Warning                  : Disabled
83c81
< BIOS Version       : 3.22.00_4.11.05.00_0x05060000
---
> BIOS Version       : 3.09.00
85,87c83,84
< Boot Block Version : 2.02.00.00-0000
< BOOT Version       : 09.250.01.219
< BreakMirror RAID Support         : No
---
> Boot Block Version : 2.00.00.00-0018
> BOOT Version       : 01.250.04.219
94d90
< ChipRevision    : B4
105,106c101,102
< Current Size of FW Cache       : 145 MB
< Current Time                     : 16:17:43 6/25, 2013
---
> Current Size of FW Cache       : 0 MB
> Current Time                     : 16:23:41 6/25, 2013
110c106
< Default spin down time in minutes: 30
---
> Default spin down time in minutes: 0
112c108
< Delay Among Spinup Groups        : 2s
---
> Delay Among Spinup Groups        : 12s
131d126
< Disable Join Mirror              : No
136c131
< Disable Spin Down of hot spares         : Yes
---
> Disable Spin Down of hot spares         : No
139d133
< Don't Auto spin down Configured Drives
151,152c145
< Enable Shield State              : No
< Enable Spin Down of UnConfigured Drives : Yes
---
> Enable Spin Down of UnConfigured Drives : No
166,167c159,160
< FW Package Build: 12.12.0-0065
< FW Version         : 2.120.143-1325
---
> FW Package Build: 12.0.1-0097
> FW Version         : 2.0.33-0901
186,187c179,180
< Max Drives to Spinup at One Time : 4
< Maximum number of direct attached drives to spin up in 1 min : 120
---
> Max Drives to Spinup at One Time : 2
> Maximum number of direct attached drives to spin up in 1 min : 0
192d184
< Max power savings option is  not allowed for LDs. Only T10 power conditions are to be used.
202c194
< Mfg. Date       : 09/17/11
---
> Mfg. Date       : 05/17/10
208c200
< NVDATA Version     : 2.09.03-0020
---
> NVDATA Version     : 2.02.0043
218c210
< Physical Devices  : 10
---
> Physical Devices  : 9
222c214
< Power Saving option              : Don't spin down Hot spares
---
> Power Saving option              : All power saving options are enabled
226c218
< Preboot CLI Version: 04.04-017:#%00008
---
> Preboot CLI Version: 02.00-015:#%00008
241c233
< Revision No     : 80B
---
> Revision No     :
243c235
< SAS Address      : 500605b003b0c060
---
> SAS Address      : 500605b00234f210
250c242
< Serial No       : SV13815228
---
> Serial No       : SV02102642
256c248
< Spin Down time                          : 30
---
> Spin Down time                          : 0
261c253
< Support Boot Time PFK Change    : Yes
---
> Support Boot Time PFK Change    : No
271,272c263,264
< Support Temperature                     : Yes
< Support the OCE without adding drives : Yes
---
> Support Temperature                     : No
> Support the OCE without adding drives : No
279d270
< TTY Log In Flash                 : No
288c279
< WebBIOS Version    : 6.0-40-e_35-Rel
---
> WebBIOS Version    : 3.0-22-e_12-Rel
```

Comment: I had lots of these in the past, but honestly I'm not sure.  Best I can say is go here: http://www-947.ibm.com/support/entry/portal/docdisplay?lndocid=MIGR-5073015 and grab the latest firmware and cli's for both and then check again.  It's possible that the 80B rev is a different part number altogether (if you have this info).  The M5014 latest is 46M0916, but there's also 46M0918 and 49Y3720.  I wonder if a call to IBM "pre sales" would get you info on any differences?

Comment: Per @TheCleaner 's suggestion a firmware update fixed the problem. A detailed solution with be posted in due it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was fixed with a firmware update. Because the M5014 card no longer resides in an IBM system I was unable to flash the card with their standard firmware package. To accomplish a firmware update I flashed the card with LSI's 9260-8i Firmware.

Note that if your firmware is before 12.7.0-0020(IBM) you will need to flash to LSI's 12.12.0-0090 firmware before you can flash to more recent versions. There was no need to boot to dos or create a complicated USB thumb drive. The following command on Debian Wheezy did the trick

```
sudo megacli -adpfwflash -f the_rom_file.rom -a0
```

Happy RAIDing.......